# Regarding fundamental group computation of the complement of a torus knot in $S^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is regarding the fundamental group computation of the complement of a toral knot in $S^3$ in Hatcher's algebraic topology book. See page 48. I have understood till the stage where the cross section of the torus minus the knot deformation-retracts to the radial segments as the arrows indicate. What is not clear is "Letting $x$ vary, these radial segments then trace out a copy of the mapping cylinder $X_m$ in the first solid torus."

I tried imagining this with a simple cases like the trefoil knot, but can't fathom this statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It helps to think of the 3 sphere as the union of two solid tori. The circles hatcher uses in the mapping cylinder construction are the cores of the solid torus plus a curve parallel to the knot in the separatingtorus.

Comment: Never thought of it this way! Will chew upon this. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It helps to think of the 3 sphere as the union of two solid tori. The circles Hatcher uses in the mapping cylinder construction are the cores of the solid torus plus a curve parallel to the knot in the separating torus.

Comment: If this is the case, then even if each torus deformation retracts onto each of these cylinders it doesn’t deformation retract onto X_mn, the original required space, since the two « cylinders » don’t intersect in the required circle no?

Comment: @LittleNarwhal the two cylinders should intersect on the curve parallel to the knot in the separating torus - which is a copy of $S^1$. This is also the 'domain' of either mapping cylinder, so it is precisely what deformation retracts onto the respective ends.

Answer (score 2):

To expound a bit:

The center of the "Y" figure is a point of $S^1$ of the mapping cylinder.
This center also wraps around the torus once as $x$ varies.
However, the tips of the "Y" wrap around the torus $m$ times.